# Python inheriting instance variable when value of the variable changes dynamically

Tags: python, inheritance

I have to inherit dynamic value of the Parent instance variable `a`.I've tried using `super` which gets the value which is defined in the `init` constructor of the Parent and also have tried passing Parent object.

Please refer the code snippet below

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def test(self):
        self.a = 2


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()


class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.a = parent.a


p = Parent()
c = Child()
c1 = Child1(p)
p.test()
print p.a  #2
print c.a  #1
print c1.a #1
```

If I use below code, the problem gets solved.However is there any way to get the instance variable value of parent which is altered after initialization.

```
c.test()
print c.a #2
c1.test()
print c1.a #2
```

Please suggest any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delegation here. Instead of directly assigning `self.a` to the value of `parent.a`, you should store the *parent*, and then define a property that gets the value of the parent's `a` on request.

```
class Child1(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.parent.a
```